# SIGTERM not trapped while command is running, but SIGINT is

Tags: bash, docker, signals

I'm building some CI pipelines, and part of it is a bash wrapper script around a docker container running ansible commands. The trouble I'm having is that on job abort the container keeps running, which is potentially dangerous.

What I have currently is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER=ansible

function kill_container() {
  echo "$0 caught $1" >&2
  docker kill ${CONTAINER}
  exit $?
}
trap 'kill_container SIGINT' SIGINT
trap 'kill_container SIGTERM' SIGTERM

function ansible_base() {
  docker run -d --rm --name ${CONTAINER} someorg/ansible:latest $@
  docker logs --follow ${CONTAINER}
}

ansible_base $@
```

and my local test is simply `./run.sh sleep 30`.

For the purpose of reproducability, you can substitute `alpine:latest` as the image and it behaves the same.

Prior to adding `-d` to the `run` and the `docker logs` it did not respect SIGINT at all, but now it works as expected. Eg:

```
./ci/run.sh sleep 30
5f5d78cfea27cdc15f5fede2003352253ae3254f44489ab4689ebca8d0f91768
^C./ci/run.sh caught SIGINT
ansible
```

However, if I run a `pkill run.sh` from another terminal it still waits the full 30 seconds before handling the signal, raising an error that the container is already gone. Eg:

```
./ci/run.sh sleep 30
a642a1060dc9d340e92dc255d68a9d9cb26d62ec59c5ef8d4e3d4198f1692c3e
./ci/run.sh caught SIGTERM
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: ansible: Container a642a1060dc9d340e92dc255d68a9d9cb26d62ec59c5ef8d4e3d4198f1692c3e is not running
```

Ultimately, the observed behaviour in the CI system is the same. The process is issued a SIGTERM, and then after not responding for 30 seconds a SIGKILL. This terminates the wrapper script, but not the docker command.

Comment: Are you running an init in your container? Like dumb init? Signal propagation is the reason they exist.

Comment: @brunson I didn't think I'd need one "since it's not a daemon" but it's not _not_ a daemon and _does_ need that. I've added tini and `ENTRYPOINT [ '/sbin/tini', '--' ]` but now I'm getting `sh: --: unknown operand` which is a new level of mystifying...

Comment: I've never used tini

Comment: I foolishly used single quotes instead of double. Having an init absolutely solved it. I'll post the detes as an answer.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out.

Comment: Side note: I urge you to quote your uses of `$@` with double quotes (`"$@"`).  This will ensure that each argument expands to a single word, even if it contains whitespace. If you do not quote it then the expansions will be subject to word splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @brunson said, I needed an init process to handle signal propagation.

When I was originally writing this my thought was "it's just a command, it doesn't need an initd" which was somewhat true until the very instant I needed it to respect signals at all. Frankly it was a foolish thought in the first place.

Anyhow, to accomplish the fix I used [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini).

Added to Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
```

and `run.sh` is back down to a much more manageable:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function ansible_base() {
  docker run --rm someorg/ansible:latest "$@"
}

ansible_base "$@"
```